# Task Instance is not defined

Tags: airflow

I have an object I've passed to xcom that I want to read from an operator.

Here is my operator:

```
load_csv = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bigquery',
    bucket='test',
    source_objects=['{{ execution_date.strftime("%Y-%m") }}'],
    providers=True,
    destination_project_dataset_table=f'{stg_dataset_name}' + '.' + '{{ execution_date.strftime("%Y_%m") }}',
    schema_fields={{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='print_the_context')}},
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

I want to pass the value from xcom to the `schema_fields` variable.

I'm trying to access the object using the following template `{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='print_the_context')}}` but I have `it is not defined`...

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment

- To be able to leverage [`macros`](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/templating/) in `operator` arguments, the corresponding field must be defined as [`template_fields`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716598/3679900) in operator's source code
- But here in the source of [`GCSToBigQueryOperator`](https://github.com/joppevos/airflow/blob/6e71065dfb5c6d9e5b361cd56d041a8664d4fa22/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs_to_bigquery.py), I see that [`schema_fields` is missing from `template_fields`](https://github.com/joppevos/airflow/blob/6e71065dfb5c6d9e5b361cd56d041a8664d4fa22/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs_to_bigquery.py#L153)

  ```
  template_fields = ('bucket', 'source_objects',
                      'schema_object', 'destination_project_dataset_table')
  ```

Therefore you can't supply value for `schema_fields` via XCOM template

---

That said, while I'm not aware of internals of [`GCSToBigQueryOperator`](https://github.com/joppevos/airflow/blob/6e71065dfb5c6d9e5b361cd56d041a8664d4fa22/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs_to_bigquery.py), I can see 2 possible solutions

- (straightforward) use [`schema_object` field](https://github.com/joppevos/airflow/blob/6e71065dfb5c6d9e5b361cd56d041a8664d4fa22/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs_to_bigquery.py#L60) instead

  ```
  :param schema_object: If set, a GCS object path pointing to a .json file that
       contains the schema for the table. (templated)
       Parameter must be defined if 'schema_fields' is null and autodetect is False.
   :type schema_object: str
  ```
- you can try subclassing it and including `schema_fields` in `template_fields`

---

Interesting reads

- [Make custom Airflow macros expand other macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44855949/3679900)
- [Airflow Jinja Rendered Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50184992/3679900)